# SP 2013 REST throws error 500 with specific Regional Settings

Tags: error, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem, regional-settings

I have built a SP-hosted app that uses REST API calls to get data from a list in the Host Web.

The request (from fiddler) is as simple as this:

```
GET https://apps-9e73cb0dc879a0.*domain*.com/sites/*hostWeb*/*appName*/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('tutor_tasks')/Items?$select=assignedToId,assignedFromId&$top=1&$filter=assignedTo%20eq%20%273%27&@target=%27https://*domain*.com/sites/*hostWeb*%27
```

When Host Web site regional settings are Locale are in English, the requests works as expected. But when I change the Local to Greek or some other languages AND it is an on-Premises SharePoint installation , I get Internal Error 500. Changing back to English and it's OK again.

It always works when the exact same app runs on O365 SharePoint no matter what Regional Settings I use.

The `tutor_tasks` list has nothing really special, two User fields and a text field.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. When switching to Greek Language, SharePoint also switches Sort Order to Greek automatically. Switching back to General Sort Order fixes this issue. I surelly cannot explain that, but tested it with outher Locales too, and for some reason it does the trick!

Comment: It has to do with the way LINQ to SharePoint works. There are other locale-related issues as well, such as reliance on localizable DisplayNames of the fields that will also break your REST calls. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58107/listdata-svc-with-complex-filters-internet-explorer-400-bad-http-request

Comment: So an obvious solution for all these issues would be to stop using REST and go with the JSOM way?

Comment: Well, if your risk assessment tells you that solution stability and agility requirements outweigh the benefits of simplified data access, then you may decide so. Like I usually do :)